# trying to do iframe and cannot figure it out

Tags: html, iframe

I want to use iframe to keep my story links in a list on the left side of my site and have the actual text of the story show on the right, in the lighter gray area, instead of a separate page. Each story is in its own html file right now. I have the page linked below so you can see how I have my link list set.

https://stf5123.github.io/Grimm_project/workstest2.html

Answer (score 0):

You can use iframe.

```
      <ul>
         <li><a class="active" target="frame" href="GoldenBird.html">Golden Bird</a></li>
         <li><a class="active"target="frame" href="hansinluck.html">Hans In Luck</a></li>
      </ul>


   <iframe name="frame" ></iframe>
```

Comment: You are awesome! Thank You so much. Now I just have top figure out how to get the frame on the right side of the screen and I am good to go.